# Why is const temporary bound to rvalue reference parameter?

Tags: c++, rvalue, overload-resolution

I have the following functions:

```
void func(void * const &ptr)
{
    std::cerr << "const" << std::endl;
}

void func(void *      &&ptr)
{
    std::cerr << "mutable" << std::endl;
}

void* const func2()
{
    return nullptr;
}
```

One overload takes const reference parameter and another takes mutable rvalue reference. And there is a function that returns const value.

When I pass that const temporary value to the function:

```
func(func2());
```

I expect the const overload to be chosen. But instead I get:

```
mutable
```

How is that possible? Why is const return value bound to non-const rvalue reference parameter?

This doesn't however happen when instead of `void*` I pass const `struct` to the function:

```
struct A
{
};

void func(A const &a)
{
    std::cerr << "const" << std::endl;
}

void func(A      &&a)
{
    std::cerr << "mutable" << std::endl;
}

A const func3()
{
    return A(); 
}

int main()
{
    func(func3());
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
const
```

You can check this on [coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d983efd4b17790d).

What is difference between const `void*` and const `struct`?

Is there a way to make overload that takes specifically const values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is const temporary bound to rvalue reference parameter?

Because it's not const by the time overload resolution happens.

> **[expr.type]**
>
> [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr#type-2) If a prvalue initially has the type “cv T”, where T is a cv-unqualified non-class, non-array type, the type of the expression is adjusted to T prior to any further analysis.

A class type prvalue retains its cv-qualifications, but not a `void* const` prvalue. Overload resolution therefore happens with a plain `void*` prvalue, which explains the behavior you observe when the rvalue overload is chosen.

The types this paragraph applies to are those "fundamental" types whose value is actually *accessed* by the program. So a prvalue of such a type is indeed a "pure", ephemeral value, and cannot be modified already.

Comment: Is there a way to make overload that takes specifically const values?

Comment: @anton_rh - You can take a `void* const &&` if you want it to be const so much. But you can't affect the type of the expression you feed into overload resolution. Or we can  just not be silly, and plainly  take a `void*` by value.

Comment: No, `void* const &&` doesn't help.

Comment: @anton_rh - If you say so. Either way, this is the answer.